# Avoid to get rounded corner after a polygon buffer (FME)

Tags: buffer, fme-form

I try to create a buffer for my polygons that leave the angles intact (not rounded).

---

- With **postgis/postgresql** I can do:

  `SELECT st_buffer(geom,5,'join=mitre') FROM mypolygon;`

---

- With **ArcGis** I can select the option `FLAT` in the buffer GUI.

---

- With **FME** I'm unable to get a correct result. Any IDEA ?

Comment: This would be great question for @MarkIreland.

Comment: Polygon buffers in FME always have round corners.  I believe you may have to convert to lines and buffer them.  Maybe do something similar to this workflow: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/83571/how-to-maintain-right-angles-when-buffering

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right now the closest you can get is to set the End Cap Style to square and the Stroking Density to 1. Inside corners get a single point, but outside corners get two points, meaning it's probably not quite what you want.

However, the Bufferer was updated for FME2017 and now includes parameters that would allow you to do keep angles intact. If you're OK with using a beta build, you can download it from http://safe.com/beta - you want build number 17070 or greater.

Comment: Looks like the 2017 betas got removed - an installer error I think - but there should be one uploaded shortly.

Comment: Thank you, Great news that's a really useful feature. So I'm going to update FME once the update is out (again) !