# Dilating a polygon by a circle sector

Tags: arcpy, shapefile, polygon, buffer

I want to dilate a polygon by a circle sector in ArcMap.

Because my python skills are not that good to figure out how I can use the R prototype of [How to create an oriented buffer using arcpy?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/69630/how-to-create-an-oriented-buffer-using-arcpy) . Is there a Python version of this script ?

[image]

In this first example, the polygon is dilated by a circle sector formed between -30 to 75 degrees

[image]

```
    # Dilate the polygon by circle sector -30 to 75 degrees
    # system.time({   radius <- 1/3   par(mfrow=c(1,3))   q <- sector(radius, pi/12, 2*pi/3, n=120)   d.points <-
    dilate.points(polygon.the, q)   d.edges <- dilate.edges(polygon.the,q)        display(polygon.the, d.points, d.edges, main="-30 to 75 degrees")
```

My cirlce sector is formed between -135 and 135 degrees, so how can I rewrite this code? Can anyone help me with writing a functional pythonscript to run this dilation in Arcmap?